# File Upload Large Files PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Im trying to find some software to help me upload really large files (>200mb). I only want to upload a single file, no multi-options. Also i would like a simple progress bar if possible.

I have come across http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/ which is literally what i need but it has a limit of 100mb per file, because it uses flash.

Does anyone know of something else thats similar to this, but can handle larger files?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another popular solution is http://www.swfupload.org/, but I guess it may suffer from the 100MB limit.

Regarding the whole issue of large file sizes, from my research it seems that in order to upload large files there is no other option than to increase the values for upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and max_execution time. I just wonder what the security implications are of having post_max_size set to, say, 500M? Its not the issue of bandwidth that concerns me - it is the possible DoS attacks that might arise from allowing attackers to send random 500M POST requests to the server. The best workaround I can think for this issue is to send uploads to a different server.

There is a good discussion of the whole issue here:

http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/how-handle-large-file-uploads

If any Apache hackers out there can shed any light on the security implications of having a really large value for post_max_size that would be great.

Comment: Apache itself doesn't really care how big the files are, modulo things like 31/32bit limits (2.1/4.2gig). But if you have a very large post limit, it is possible to tie up all available children in the connection pool with long-lived uploads and DOS the machine (as well as exhaust disk space). This is harder to do with smaller limits as the uploads will complete quicker and recycle connections faster. Of course, you can just totally slam the server with connection attempts anyways.

Comment: max_execution_time only affects the execution time of the script itself. Therefore does not impact the time taken for the actual file upload. You need to increase **max_input_time** significantly. It sets the maximum time, in seconds, the script is allowed to receive input (including the file upload itself). Default is 60 seconds.

Comment: So, **max_input_time** should be at least 1500 if your max file size is 500 MB. **Why?** Because avg upload speed is about 500kbps. Or 1 MB every 2 seconds. 500(MB) * 2 sec = 1000 Seconds. And some users might have slower internet or be using some of their bandwidth for other tasks, so a cushion of an extra 500 or so would be good.
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score 2):

You can try using HTML5 and AJAX to handle large file uploads. In a combination with PHP streams you'll get very low memory usage. Here a link with more details:

http://www.webiny.com/blog/2012/05/07/webiny-file-upload-with-html5-and-ajax-using-php-streams/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing a Java uploader, like [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/) and integrate it with your current system. It has extensive API and its JScript interface is easily accessibly as well. You can, as I did, code your server side handler and make it capable of:

1. Multiple file uploading
2. Uploads without any limits in filesize - I am currently struggling with PHP's 2G limit on fopen(), but I expect to solve soon
3. Partitioned uploading - file gets uploaded in chunks
4. Transmission integrity - JumpLoader can also calculate and send md5 checksums for every partition and the whole file itself, which you can validate in server side to see whether the package arrived ok or not.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://www.uploadify.com

Comment: Thx for that :). Since it (and other similar tools out there) simply uses the html 'file' input type to render and upload files.. do you think having to change the php upload limits would create security holes?

Comment: Of course. Someone could eat up your bandwidth easily. But your considering security holes now before developing which is good. You can therefore do you best to fill those holes early rather than later.