# AJAX form - uploading multiple images

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax call, to upload multiple images from javascript. The code works well when I have a few images but as soon as I increase the files uploaded at the same time (ex: 530 files), the php does not receive anything. Any help to solve this issue please?

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formdata = new FormData(this);
formdata.append('regId', document.getElementById('register_id').value);


$.ajax({
    url: 'uploadImages.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "<p>"+response+"</p>";
    },
});
```

});

I tried to increase the max_upload_size and max_file_uploads from apache2 as this example:

https://connectwww.com/how-to-change-php-file-upload-size-limit-in-ubuntu/5087/

But still it does not work.

Comment: may be max upload size or any other criteria u need to check also.

Comment: Check webserver configuration.

Comment: The files are all images and approximately all the same size. The problem is when I start uploading a large amount of files

Comment: I noticed that only 12 files can be uploaded at the same time.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562274/file-upload-large-files-php-ajax

Comment: show the html part

Comment: The files are usually uploaded one file at at time so `max_upload_size` is not your issue. Try increasing the [post_max_size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: post_max_size fixed it :) Thank you so much!